# Can't get a counter working in tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

```py
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

import tweepy
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream


import time



consumer_key = 'super secret consumer key'
consumer_secret = 'shhhhh can't tell anyone this!'
access_token = 'hmmmmmmmmmmmmm'
access_secret = 'arrays should start at 0'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
print('')
print('starting...')
time.sleep(3)

class MySteamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):







    def on_status(self, status):
        #prints status text. can be replaced with a counter probably.
        counter = counter + 1
        print(status.text)


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            print('420 error')
            #Ends stream in case of rate limiting
            return False


mySteamListener = MySteamListener()

myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener = mySteamListener)

myStream.filter(track = ['Warriors'])
```

I'm new to tweepy, and the first thing I'm trying to do is make a program that scans all tweets for certain words. Everything was working well until I tried to add a counter for the number of instances for that word. No matter where I assign the counter, I always get a 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment' error. Where should I assign the counter in this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "can't" above is not really in your code, if possible update your question to omit the "'" as it messes up the readability or change to some other placeholder text.

As the error indicates, you have not assigned a value yet to counter, the method "on_status" will try to increment counter, but this is only local to the method, not the object, thus it fails.

```
def on_status(self, status):
        #prints status text. can be replaced with a counter probably.
        counter = counter + 1
        print(status.text)
```

You should initialize the counter in an **init** method and then use self.counter instead.

Add

```
...
class MySteamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        # Not sure if necessary, to make this work, but you could
        # Initialize the inherited class as well (this may work only in Python 3)
        # super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0
...
```

Modify on_status to

```
def on_status(self, status):
        #prints status text. can be replaced with a counter probably.
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        # Can be written as 'self.counter += 1'
        print(status.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. And by 'worked' I mean I'm getting a different error message. However, The counter problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Trying to help you in your follow up question, could you please accept this answer if it solved your problem ?